# Fixed header bar has gap in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

For some reason I'm getting a top margin of about 10px above my header bar in Firefox, but not in Chrome.  This doesn't effect the main body, just the fixed header bar.  If I remove the position: fixed; then there is no gap, but then it is no longer fixed.

Gap marked in red:

[image: problem marked in red]

```css
   body {
     margin: 0px;
   }
   #topbar {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: #F0F0F0;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 10000;
   }
   #topbar .header {
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 35;
     color: darkgrey;
     margin-top: 5px;
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="nav_item">
      <button class="nav_icon"></button>
      <nav>
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">Item 1</a>
        <a href="">Item 2</a>
        <a href="">Logout</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following css:

```
#topbar {
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: This actually works!  Is this somehow different from margin?

Comment: @Nick yes, when you use `position: fixed` or `absolute` its better to use `top' , `left', 'right` or `bottom' according to our needs to avoid cross browser issues...

Comment: @Nick please remove downvote from my answer if it is helpful

Comment: I've tried, but I can't, says I don't have 15 reputation yet.  It wasn't me who downvoted you.

Comment: @ 15 reputation, yes you have now :)